# How to configure ReflectInsight log viewer to read nlog data from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog, reflectinsight

I'm currently using Nlog to log ASP.Net exception to database. So far exceptions are logging, and it is working fine.

I would like to view them back using [ReflectInsight](http://www.reflectsoftware.com/)'s fancy logviewer.

[image]

I follow [Getting Started with NLog Extension](http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20NLog%20Extension&referringTitle=Documentation).

***I could not find any documentation regarding how to connect to database from ReflectInsight.***

Could someone please point me to the right direciton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReflectInsight framework only receives messages from their extensions (i.e., in your case NLog extension). From your application, when it sends log messages via NLog, the RI framework will route them to its configured listeners configured in your application. If no listeners have been configured, it will default to the Live Viewer as shown in your screenshot.

You can however, configure your application to store RI messages to a binary file with rotations configured. This way, if any problems do occur in production, you can request the logs from your operations and filter the issues from there.

Our future product will have a web version (HTML5) to allow you to view RI messages stored specifically in the database. However, the database will be proprietary format specifically for RI.

If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to ask or provide feedback here: http://reflectsoftware.uservoice.com/

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the developers of ReflectInsight.

Comment: All docs have been moved from CodePlex to the following url: https://reflectsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RI5/ReflectInsight+5+documentation

Also the source code that was hosted on CodePlex is now on GitHub: https://github.com/reflectsoftware